# Magento Bug? - Can't subscribe to Newsletter with registered email that is not subscribed

Tags: magento, newsletter

2 emails are registered users of my Magento store:

```
user1@example.com
user2@example.com
```

When registering, user1@example.com opted in the Newsletter while user2@example.com **did not**.

However when user2@example.com tried to sign up with the Newsletter (the Newsletter sign-up form meant for guests) when logged out, Magento gives an error:

```
There was a problem with the subscription: This email address is already assigned to another user.
```

Would this be classified as a bug? Because everybody loses in here: the store loses one potential lead, and the customer gets frustrated because it didn't fulfill what he or she wanted.

How can I circumvent this before Magento team solves it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a bug, it's intended behaviour. If user2@example.com is logged in and they enter then they will be signed up. You only get this message if user2.example.com is a registered user AND you are not logged in as that user.

If you wish to change this behaviour, you will need to edit line 58 of Mage_Newsletter_SubscriberController.

Nb. You shouldn't edit the core file, if you want to change it you really should overload the class.

Comment: It might not be a bug but I agree with @kavoir.com that it's unwanted behavior. I think it would be better if Magento would redirect the user to the account login page. It could still show the message that the e-mail address is already registered and that it's therefore required to log in to subscribe,.

Comment: I guess it's a matter of opinion. It's obviously put in place to prevent me from subscribing you to the newsletter. Perhaps the message should say something different, or perhaps if you aren't logged in, as you say redirect to login. The user can obviously change their subscription status once logged in.

Comment: Yeah, I think Magento should still notify the user that: 1) the email is already registered in the system, 2) and the owner must LOG IN with the email so as to sign up with the newsletter.